# tinyMCE style_formats not using CSS-imported fonts

Tags: css, fonts, tinymce

I have a tinyMCE implementation where the `style_formats` are not using the CSS imported font as a preview in the format selector.  Oddly, it *does* display the font in the editor portion (see screenshot)

I have added the stylesheet containing the `@font-face` specifications in `content_css` property for tinyMCE.

[image: tinyMCE screenshot]

If I load the page on a system with that font installed, it uses the font in the formats menu as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a tinyMCE issue at all.

I was adding an `@import` for the font CSS in the tinyMCE custom CSS.  It could be that I'm dynamically loading the view containing the tinyMCE implementation, but including the font CSS using a `<link>` tag in the wrapper template solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the content window for TinyMCE is an iFrame so its separate from the containing page where you are loading TinyMCE.  The Menubar, Toolbar(s) etc are not in that iFrame but are part of your main containing page that includes TinyMCE.

As such for both to have access to a font both need to load the font.  Loading it in the CSS that you pass to the editor (via `content_css`) solves that for the content window but does not address the containing page.  If you load that same font in the containing page things will work as expected.  Based on your description I believe this is working as designed.